# Change header styleClass of a panel

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have panels and would like to change the header's background color of only one of them. Thus I can't juste change the `ui-panel-titlebar` style.

I tried the following without success.

```html
<p:panel ....>
    <f:facet name="header" styleClass="ui-panel-my-titlebar">
        ....
    </f:facet>
</p:panel>
```

If I put the styleClass in the `p:panel` tag, then is the background of the content change too.

My styleClass:

```css
.ui-panel-my-titlebar {
    background: #BBBBBB;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got it to work with the following:

```html
<p:panel styleClass="customTitleBar">
  <f:facet name="header">
    ....
  </f:facet>
</p:panel>
```

css:

```css
.customTitleBar > .ui-panel-titlebar {
    background: #BBBBBB;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
:host ::ng-deep {
  .p-panel .p-panel-header {
    padding: 0.5rem;
    background: linear-gradient(-206deg, #4b6cb7 5%, #182848 100%);
    color: #ffffff;
  }
}
```

This is working with PrimeNG.

Comment: What is ng-deep? Are you sure you are using PrimeFaces? Aren't you using PrimeNG?

Comment: Yes, This is PreimeNG, PrimeFlex curated CSS only. Its perfectly working from me.

Comment: The question is about PrimeFaces, which doesn't use `.p-panel .p-panel-header` as classes.